# Detect mobile browsers and change hover behavior accordingly

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web

Occasionally I'd like to be able to publish a question from a mobile browser, or otherwise use StackExchange. However, some of the site UI elements do not appear without some kind of hovering, such as the comment upvote and flag buttons. Problem is, 'hover' is awkward on touchscreens.

While this hover behavior makes the site more usable on a desktop, in a mobile environment, it makes things unusable.

It would be awesome if the site would detect that it's using, say, Internet Explorer in Windows Phone, and not hide those things simply because a hover event has not occurred.

Comment: It is possible, but really awkward - especially since the buttons are *invisible* and *10px apart*. More than in one instance, I incidentally the whole comment when meaning to flag.

Comment: +1 Yes please! It's tricky when you have to jump through hoops to make the icons appear.

Comment: The new [Mobile Theme](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96107/help-us-alpha-test-the-stack-exchange-mobile-theme) addresses your hover problems.  MSO only at the moment.

Comment: Also I cannot remove comments in the mobile version because of this. Sucks .

Comment: You could allow the user to click on a comment's text or blank area to display the otherwise hidden hover-active elements. That's the first thing I tried and had to find out it doesn't work :)

Comment: This has been implemented; see [Why are the comment upvote and flag options always appearing now?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312794/why-are-the-comment-upvote-and-flag-options-always-appearing-now)