# Flagging a comment displays the word "flag", changes to image of red flag upon reload

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, flags, comment-flags

Since [this change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312794/why-are-the-comment-upvote-and-flag-options-always-appearing-now) was just rolled out, I noticed a bug in flagging comments.

When I submit a comment flag, the vote and flag buttons change to the word "flag" in red-colored text:

> [image: "flag [comment text here]"]

Then, after I reload the page, it then changes to an image of a red flag:

> [image]

Shouldn't it always display the red flag symbol?

Reproduced on both Microsoft Edge and Internet Explorer 11.

Comment: Heh... The indicator was a sprite referenced in styles triggered by client-side generated markup. Now those styles are gone, replaced by inline SVGs... But the client-side markup is still there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has been fixed and will go out during the next build. Thanks for reporting!