# Comments no longer indicate whether or not they've been edited

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, user-interface

Today, the comment UI received a [revamp](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312794/why-are-the-comment-upvote-and-flag-options-always-appearing-now).

However, as part of that, the indication that a comment had been edited (a [pencil icon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/33939/300713)) seems to have been removed, as well.

This doesn't seem like it's an intentional change, and may have been accidentally left out as part of the new changes. Could we get the icon back, please?

Comment: This comment has been edited, but it doesn't look like it!

Comment: The pencil is there, it's just not visible. `style="display: inline-block;height: 11px;width: 11px"` makes it visible again.

Comment: an update to the [ReduceClutter](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/ReduceClutter.user.js) userscript temporarily fixes this

Comment: @Stijn Just FYI: The CSS that used to be used was: `.edited-yes { display: inline-block; vertical-align: text-bottom; line-height: 12px; height: 15px; width: 16px }`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This has been fixed in the latest build. Thanks for reporting!