# Comment flag recent UI change is not updated in the flag posts privilege page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comment-flags, privileges-page

The UI behavior of the comment flag is [recently changed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312794/312043). ie., the comments flag option is appearing always. But in all the site's "Flag Posts" ( `https://<site-name>/help/privileges/flag-posts`) privilege page, the information about the comment flag is still the old content mentioning about "Hover over a comment".

The content from the [MSE Flag Posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts):

> Hover over a comment and click the flag icon [image] to the left and you will see the pop-up dialog pictured below.

Can be the content in the flag posts privilege page, updated as per the new UI design?