# Comment flag dialog recent UI change to be updated in Flag Posts privilege page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comment-flags, privileges-page

Recently the UI changed for the [flagging comments dialog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/313436/312043). In the privileges page for the [Flag Posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts), the old UI image is still being used for the **Comment** section.

Can the new UI be displayed on all Stack Exchange site's **Flag Posts** privilege page.

---

**UPDATE:** After the [new comment flagging rolled out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313754/312043) the UI dialog is changed again.

> [image: New UI for flagging comments]

---

Note: There is another [feature-request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313018/312043) regarding the comment flag recent UI change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recent comment flag UI dialog is changed in the [Flag Posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) privilege page, long time before.

> [image: Flag posts]