# Why are images shown next to each comment?

Tags: support, comments, design, user-interface

In my opinion it would look cleaner if the comment images/buttons were only shown when hovering over the comments (on desktop). Why are they always shown?

[image]

Comment: IIRC it was like that 6 to 8 months ago ... the re-design to Stacks changed that to have the options always visible so anyone is aware they can act on comments.

Comment: Luckily there is a user script to fix this: https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/ReduceClutter.user.js

Comment: see related post: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312794/why-are-the-comment-upvote-and-flag-options-always-appearing-now

Comment: It was changed in order to better support mobile devices, which lack the hover effect.