# Please implement a way to see post timestamps on the mobile site

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web, timestamps

On the desktop site, when looking at posts that are recent enough, sometimes the site just says "1 hour ago."

[image: An image of Stormblessed's profile with "answered 1 hour ago" above it]

However, if I hover over it, it shows a nice little timestamp:

[image: A timestamp saying the exact time the post is from on Stormblessed's profile]

I would love to be able to see post timestamps on the mobile site. While posts that are old enough show the hour and minute they are from, it is, as far as I know, impossible to get these for recent posts.

Comment: On hover works for me on the mobile view in Chrome. Is this a specific issue for mobile-safari?

Comment: @rene how do you hover on your phone? Holding my finger on the “__ hours ago” doesn’t work in mine in Safari or Firefox

Comment: I assume it should be replaced with a touch event but a [quick search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=+touch+is%3Aq+%5Bbug%5D+-%5Bstatus*%5D) shows that is lacking on more places. The data is there so it shouldn't be much of a problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect mobile browsers and change hover behavior accordingly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95446/detect-mobile-browsers-and-change-hover-behavior-accordingly). While the examples it offers are "comment upvote" and "flag" (and *those* are fixed), there are [half a dozen 'hover touchscreen' not working](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=hover%20touchscreen) complaints. Being a touchscreen user I wish they'd change the library and get this working on all touchscreens/Browsers/OSes.

Comment: @Rob Not a duplicate. That doesn't mention tooltips, but rather buttons (a.k.a. site functionality).

Comment: @SonictheWizardWerehog It's hovering, in general, on whatever. We welcome a better duplicate ***because*** when there are two or three they all get shown on the top 'Duplicate Banner'., so additional suggestions are useful.

Comment: One way is via [adding a click event](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174854/add-click-event-to-trigger-timestamp-tooltips). Since there may be other ways, closed the older one as dupe of this one.